# Как настроить автозагрузку syncthing в CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, синхронизация, systemd, автозагрузка

Установил syncthing, пытаюсь настроить автозагрузку systemd согласно [инструкции](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html):

Файл /usr/lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for %I
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)
After=network.target
Wants=syncthing-inotify@.service

[Service]
User=%i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
Restart=on-failure
SuccessExitStatus=3 4
RestartForceExitStatus=3 4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Источник: [github.com/syncthing/syncthing/tree/master/etc/linux-systemd](http://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/tree/master/etc/linux-systemd)

Делаю команды:

```
systemctl enable syncthing@root.service
systemctl start syncthing@root.service
systemctl status syncthing@root.service
```

В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
systemctl status syncthing@root
● syncthing@root.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for root
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2016-12-05 08:07:35 MSK; 8h ago
     Docs: man:syncthing(1)
  Process: 11600 ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11600 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 05 08:07:35 user systemd[1]: Unit syncthing@root.service entered failed state.
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: syncthing@root.service failed.
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: syncthing@root.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for syncthing@root.service
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: Failed to start Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for root.
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: Unit syncthing@root.service entered failed state.
Dec 05 08:07:35 user  systemd[1]: syncthing@root.service failed.
```

Если запускать просто командой `syncthing` все ок. Куда копать?

Comment: `which syncthing` чё выдаёт?

Comment: Проблему решил указанием правильного пути к bin файлу syncthing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно указан путь `ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing`

Проверить путь, указать правильный